# How to change boxplot to bar plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have had some code written for me to produce a mixed linear effects model with box plots. I am a complete beginner with R and I am trying to learn how to alter the code to produce a barplot.

This is what I have been given to produce a boxplot:

```
    ana2$B<-factor(ana2$Burn,c("N","L","S"))
    with(ana2,boxplot(Time~ana2$B*Graze))
```

[current boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3HcX.png)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boxplot in R base is blessed with a formula interface (in your case `Time~ana2$B*Graze` is the formula). This makes it easy to combine factor levels to generate a grouping of the boxplots (see `?boxplot`  for help). The base `barplot` is more limited. It will require that you wrangle your data into a "long" format with one variable being the "height" (I guess you would go for the mean) and one being a dummy variable for all levels of `ana2$B*Graze`. As you are learning I would recommend to immediately have a look at some of the  packages in the `[tidyverse][1]` for these challenges. Wrangling data is greatly simplified by the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages for which there is a good cheat sheet [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) (I look at it very often myself). For visualisation, you may immediately want to have a look at the `ggplot2` package. Here, as an alternative to your formula interface you could take benefit of using `geom_bar()` in combination with `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()`. Dplyr and ggplot2 changed the way I use R for the better, so for a learner I think it is very nice to use them from the start.